# Exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException was thrown while trying to retrieve a Discussion Board

Tags: 2003

I am trying to retrieve a Discussion Board from SP2003.I have used Web Services for doing this. 
The method of the web service is

```
GetListItems(Url, listName, viewName, ndQuery, ndViewFields, rowLimit, ndQueryOptions)
 where listName is GUID of the list
       viewName is null
    ndQuery = <OrderBy><FieldRef Name="ID" /></OrderBy><Where><Eq><FieldRef              Name="ContentType" /><Value Type="Computed">Folder</Value></Eq></Where>
    ndViewFeilds= fields of the list such as ID
    ndQueryOptions =<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns><Folder>Lists/Umesh Discussion Board</Folder><ViewAttributes Type="HTML" ModerationType="Moderator" />
```

While the query works for the higher versions of SP ie above SP2003, it returns `Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException`  in SP2003.
Please help me out. Is there anything wrong in the query?